# Excel Formula For If

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Ok. I'm Having A Problem With A formula That Seems Really Basic. It Uses The If Function. Here's What I Need.

```
If(b2:b50<>"",IF(b2:b50"607734",e2:e50="Patriot"))
```

So Basically If Between b2-b50 Has The Number "607734" I Want e2-e50 To Display "Patriot"

Comment: You would need to write an if statement in each cell you want populated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the `IF` statement in the cell where you want the value. For example, in `E2`, enter `=IF(B2="607734", "Patriot", "")` and drag it down to `E50`.

Comment: Thats What Ive Been Doing..I Used Your formula you suggested as well...Still No Good

Comment: @NIRU_Uzumaki: Try changing the condition to `B2=607734`, without the quotes.

Comment: or to avoid problems `=IF(N(B2)=607734, "Patriot", "")` ;)

Comment: Yes! It Worked Without The Quotes. Ok So. IF I wanted To Expand That and Make It To Where If B= 607734 E="patriot" OR  if B Says 412090416 E="MC95 WLP". I Actually Need That 1 Giant Formula. Could That Be Possible? jsheeran

Comment: In that case, you probably want to make a table containing the lookup keys and values, and use `VLOOKUP` to get the appropriate value from that table.

Comment: So theres No way To Make An Or/IF Formula? Like I Cant Say =IF(B2=607734, "Patriot",OR(IF(b2=412090416,"MC95 WLP","")"")

Comment: You can do that; the syntax is `=IF(B2=607734, "Patriot", IF(B2=412090416, "MC95 WLP", ""))`. But if you have 7 things that you want to look up then it's as ugly as hell, and if you have more than 7 then you can't do it.

Comment: Jesus Christ It Worked!! Thank You Very Much jSheeran I Greatly Appreciate It

Answer (score 1):

For each cell you have to enter the formula, which goes like this.

If(logical_test,value if true, value if false)

So, if b2 =607734 then c2 = "Patriot" else c2= " " 
 Now as formula we can write this as

```
if(b2=607734,"Patriot","")
```

similarly, for other cells(c3,c4,c5,c6....c50) we have formula in each cell as :

```
if(b3=607734,"Patriot","")
if(b4=607734,"Patriot","")
if(b5=607734,"Patriot","")
if(b6=607734,"Patriot","")
........
........
if(b50=607734,"Patriot","")
```

Answer (score -2):

Your IF statements don't satisfy the else conclusion.

The format of an IF statement in Excel is as follows:

IF(parameter, what to do if parameter is true, what to do if parameter is false).
Right now you've filled in the first two variables for the IF command, but you left the third blank.

e.g.

Could have:

If(b2:b50<>"",IF(b2:b50"607734",e2:e50="Patriot", " ")," ")

And in that case it would put a space in the cell if the first two conditions are not met.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. There are several things wrong with the if statement, and the one you bring up is probably the lowest offense.